# how i can customize the search button in blognegine.net

Tags: search, content-management-system, blogs, blogengine.net

i implemented last time blogengine.net 2.0 many place and they work fine. now when i make a new theme in blogengine.net 2.0 then a problem is come that

http://blogengine.codeplex.com/discussions/250959

how i can customize the search button if i want to make them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](http://rtur.net/blog/post/2010/09/08/How-to-convert-theme-to-BlogEngineNET-part-2.aspx) explains it in details.